# What defines an explicit grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

MDN defines an explicit grid with the [following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout#implicit_and_explicit_grids):

> Whereas the explicit grid consists of any rows and columns defined with grid-template-columns or grid-template-rows.

So an explicit grid can have a **single** `grid-template-columns`/`grid-template-rows`?

e.g

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 75px;
}
```

According to the definition this css should create an explicit grid as it contains a `grid-template-columns`, and thus `grid-auto-rows` should not apply, or only apply on the grid tracks at grid row 2 or below, but it applies to all the grid tracks.

[image]

However, if I apply a `grid-template-columns` **and** `grid-template-rows` it seems an explicit grid is created.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 20px;
  grid-auto-rows: 75px;
}
```

[image]

Am I misunderstanding the definition of an explicit grid, or am I missing something?

Comment: In your first example the rows are *implicit* not *explicit`*

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah that's what I ended up assuming too. The MDN docs wording is a bit confusing on specifying that you need both grid-template-rows AND grid-template-columns for an explicit grid though

Comment: It actually says "or" not "and"... as shown in your quote above.

Comment: If only grid-template-columns is specified, then you have an explicit grid of the number of specified columns, and _zero_ rows.

Answer (score 1):

> thus grid-auto-rows should not apply, or only apply on the grid tracks at grid row 2 or below, but it applies to all the grid tracks.

You are misunderstanding `grid-auto-rows`

> The grid-auto-columns and grid-auto-rows properties **specify the size of tracks not assigned a size by grid-template-rows or grid-template-columns**. If multiple track sizes are given, the pattern is repeated as necessary to find the size of the affected tracks. The first track after the last explicitly-sized track receives the first specified size, and so on forwards; <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#propdef-grid-auto-rows)</sup>

`grid-auto-rows` doesn't size only the implicit rows but any rows (including the explicit ones) that aren't sized. In your first example, you defined 2 explicit columns and you have 5 elements so you will end with 3 implicit rows all of them sized with `grid-auto-rows`

In your last example, you defined 2 columns and 1 row (with a size) so the browser will use `grid-auto-rows` to defined the size of the remaining 2 rows.

Here is another example:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    ". ."
    ". ."
    ". ."
    ". ."
    ". .";
  grid-auto-rows: 75px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
</div>
```

I defined a grid with 2 explicit columns and 5 explicit rows but no sizing. The browser will make all the rows equal to `75px`